# puppeteer v19.10.1 in docker fails on macOS [0424/114437.819230:FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(127)] No usable sandbox

Tags: node.js, docker, macos, puppeteer

#### Bug expectation

I am trying out puppeteer script in docker on macOS

I run

`docker run -i --init --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN --rm ghcr.io/puppeteer/puppeteer:latest node -e "$(cat coremakepdf.js)"`

or  (without `--cap-add=SYS_ADMIN` )

`docker run -i --init --rm ghcr.io/puppeteer/puppeteer:latest node -e "$(cat coremakepdf.js)"`

coremakepdf.js script content:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://developer.chrome.com/docs/puppeteer/get-started/', {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
    });
    await page.pdf({ path: 'developer.chrome.com.pdf', format: 'a4' });

    await browser.close();
})();
```

non-PDF related script fails with similar error, so actual script does not matter, but running in docker

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
 
(async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    // await page.goto('chrome://settings/help');
    // (node:24252) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: net::ERR_INVALID_URL at chrome://settings/help
    //await page.goto('https://example.com/'); //OK
    //await page.goto('https://developer.chrome.com/docs/puppeteer/get-started/'); //OK
    await page.goto('https://developer.chrome.com/docs/puppeteer/get-started/', {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
    }); //OK

    await page.screenshot({ path: 'about3.png' });

    await browser.close();
})();
```

```
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested

  Puppeteer old Headless deprecation warning:
    In the near feature `headless: true` will default to the new Headless mode
    for Chrome instead of the old Headless implementation. For more
    information, please see https://developer.chrome.com/articles/new-headless/.
    Consider opting in early by passing `headless: "new"` to `puppeteer.launch()`
    If you encounter any bugs, please report them to https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/new/choose.

/home/pptruser/node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/cjs/launch.js:262
                reject(new Error([
                       ^

Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
[0424/114437.785256:ERROR:stack_trace_posix.cc(811)] Failed to parse the contents of /proc/self/maps
[0424/114437.819230:FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(127)] No usable sandbox! Update your kernel or see https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/linux/suid_sandbox_development.md for more information on developing with the SUID sandbox. If you want to live dangerously and need an immediate workaround, you can try using --no-sandbox.
#0 0x004007d22f72 base::debug::CollectStackTrace()
#1 0x004007d0f4b3 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#2 0x004007c61fbf logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
#3 0x00400647ec16 content::ZygoteHostImpl::Init()
#4 0x0040071b8b23 content::ContentMainRunnerImpl::Initialize()
#5 0x0040071b6427 content::RunContentProcess()
#6 0x0040071b6606 content::ContentMain()
#7 0x0040077a01fa headless::HeadlessShellMain()
#8 0x0040038d7255 ChromeMain
#9 0x004010fa5d0a __libc_start_main
#10 0x0040038d702a _start

qemu: uncaught target signal 5 (Trace/breakpoint trap) - core dumped


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting

    at Interface.onClose (/home/pptruser/node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/cjs/launch.js:262:24)
    at Interface.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at Interface.close (node:internal/readline/interface:533:10)
    at Socket.onend (node:internal/readline/interface:259:10)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

Node.js v18.16.0
```

#### Bug behavior

- [ ] Flaky
- [ ] PDF

#### Minimal, reproducible example

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://developer.chrome.com/docs/puppeteer/get-started/', {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
    });
    await page.pdf({ path: 'developer.chrome.com.pdf', format: 'a4' });

    await browser.close();
})();
```

#### Error string

Error: Failed to launch the browser process! [0424/114437.785256:ERROR:stack_trace_posix.cc(811)] Failed to parse the contents of /proc/self/maps [0424/114437.819230:FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(127)] No usable sandbox! Update your kernel or see https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/linux/suid_sandbox_development.md for more information on developing with the SUID sandbox. If you want to live dangerously and need an immediate workaround, you can try using --no-sandbox.

#### Puppeteer configuration

```
const {join} = require('path');

/**
 * @type {import("puppeteer").Configuration}
 */
module.exports = {
    // Changes the cache location for Puppeteer.
    cacheDirectory: join(__dirname, '.cache', 'puppeteer'),
};
```

#### Puppeteer version

19.10.1

#### Node version

v18.16.0

#### Package manager

yarn

#### Package manager version

1.22.19

#### Operating system

macOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was docker issue. Solved via enabling Rosetta:

In Docker settings, in the Feature in development section, enable Rosetta.
and restart Docker

[image]

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/docker-on-apple-silicon-mac-how-to-run-x86-containers-with-rosetta-2-4a679913a0d5

Comment: I've been searching everywhere for a solution and this solved it! Thanks for coming back and answering your own question!

Comment: FYI in the end, I use both arm64 base image to run on Mac and amd64 to run on server. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76475219/playwright-java-inside-docker-runtimeexception-failed-to-create-driver